# React Native - How to handle TextInput onChangeText event to wait before execute function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I have a search function using Text Input in React native, but the search need to call an API, so I want to hold the `onChangeText` to run when user finish typing for 2 second,

I've tried to use `setInterval` nor `setTimeout` but none of these works,

here's the code I've tried:

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="search"
  onChangeText={(text) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(text)
      console.log("Kepanggil TimeOUTNYAA")
      params.onSearchText(text)
    }, 2000);
  }
}

//function onSearchText

onSearchText(searchText){
  this.setState({text:searchText},()=>{
    this._loadMore() // here's a function to call the API
  })
}
```

***Actual Behavior:***

when I'm type `am` in `TextInput` the log showing me:

[image: Actual]

***Expected Behavior:***

I want the log showing me **only** `am` **not** `a` and `am`

it is possible to do that?

Answer (score 6):

you should clear old timeout before set the new one

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="search"
    onChangeText={(text) => {
        if(this.searchWaiting)
            clearTimeout(this.searchWaiting);
        this.searchWaiting = setTimeout(() => {
            this.searchWaiting = null;
            console.log(text);
            console.log("Kepanggil TimeOUTNYAA")
            params.onSearchText(text)
        }, 2000);
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

you simply can not put `setTimeOut` or any kind of code on `onChangeText`.Its call back function that means after the event fire u received some `text` that is useless in your scenario(bcz event is fired and API is called in `onSearchText` ).

what u can do is in your `onSearchText` function you can conditionally returns `text` like if the text length is greater then 2 or 3 then only call the `API`.Like this:

```
onSearchText(searchText){
  if(searchText.length > 3){
      this.setState({text:searchText},()=>{
         this._loadMore() // here's a function to call the API
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: but how if i'm put `setTimeout` inside `onSearchText` function itself? my problem is when I dont hold the API function: when I'm typing another text and the function not yet finish, the function will running again (because of async though)

Comment: ohh.. I think its not possible bcz its basic functionality of onChangeText event :)

Comment: if it helps then mark this answer as completed please :)

Comment: This doesn't work in this case because it throws an error when you try to return the text. It happens because of the rendering issue with the react native. Thus for that I think you missed the point where you have to first intially hold the value from the textInput, which is not possible in this case.